# Elastic Load Balancer (Elastic Beanstalk) vs NGINIX

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, load-balancing

I am pretty new to AWS deployment (please send any helpful guides). And I read that it comes with an elastic load balancer but I've also heard that a lot of people put NGINX on an EC2 to use as a load balancer.

Do people commonly use either or? Having two seems redundant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nginx on an EC2 instance for load balancing would be a single point of failure, if the EC2 instance went down your app would be down. An AWS Load Balancer is actually multiple load balancer nodes distributed across multiple AWS availability zones to provide high availability. The EC2 instance would also be something for you to have to manage, where an AWS Load Balancer is managed for you by Amazon.

You mention Elastic Beanstalk in your question title. Elastic Beanstalk will use both. It uses a Load Balancer for distributing traffic across multiple instances, and it uses Nginx on each instance as a reverse proxy to your application.

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly! That was really helpful. So Elastic Beanstalk has NGINX prebuilt in or do I need to make another EC2 instance on it and install NGINX to do a reverse proxy. Also, wouldn't a reverse proxy be a single point of failure too since it is the 'face' of my application?

Comment: Elastic Beanstalk has Nginx built in, on every EC2 instance, in addition to the app you are deploying. An instance of the reverse proxy is running on each instance, so it is not a single point of failure.